# Using FTP to connect to Linux machines using Nautilus's location entry

Tags: wireless, server, nautilus, ftp, lan

I use `ifconfig` to get an IP address, but for each address from that output I put in it keeps coming up "not found".

[image: This machine is connected via direct Ethernet to the router, but which is the IP address I need?]
This machine is connected via direct Ethernet to the router, but which is the IP address I need?

The 2 computers are on the same local network using Ethernet for the one being connected TO and Wifi for the one connecting FROM, both on the same router. I did it before and actually saved it as a "bookmark" and told it to always remember the login and password so I had instant access. I even accessed the machine's CD drive and played videos and games that way through Wine, just using the "server" machine for the drive. Back then I did not do anything to specially start a FTP process or anything, Just put in the IP address in the Location bar and enter, then the login username and password.

How do I find out the specific IP address and port to connect with?

Also, if it would be simpler and easier to use something besides FTP please tell me. I just want to have access to the full file system including mounted external devices.

Comment: `ifconfig` would get you your own IP address, not the address of the server. Also, an FTP server process should be running on the server (see e.g. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html) if you need help with that). If the server is running, and you know its IP address, then pressing CTRL + L in Nautilus brings up the location bar, and typing `ftp://ipaddress_of_server/` should bring up a login screen.

Comment: This is not a "server" I was using that as a name for the other PC on my network. I do ifconfig on that desktop PC that I am trying to connect TO. Not what I am connecting FROM. I am not an educated advanced user by anymeans. I think I thought of doing this because of an android app that uses FTP to connect to it from a PC. Some how I got it to work before. But I can't now. :-(

Comment: The easiest way to find out the LAN (local) IP address of an Ubuntu computer is to click on the **Network Connection** icon at the top right corner and select **Connection information**. The machine you want to connect to (the IP address you want to connect to) must run FTP daemon `ftpd` as a service at all times. FTP uses port 20, SFTP runs on top of SSH and uses port 22 by default. If you use SFTP, then sshd must be running in the IP address you want to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your both machines are on the same 'logical' network and you could ping each other. If your local IP adress is, for example, '192.168.0.1' then your remote machine should be on that same subnet e.g. '192.168.0.2'. Find out the adress which is on the same subnet using ifconfig on the remote machine, then try to ping this adress from your local machine. Post the details and i'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use names to refer to your machines on the network, rather than IPs. You should be able to configure a DHCP+DNS server like *dnsmasq* fairly easily, to allow you to provide meaningful names that you will remember.

Beyond that, the device you are connecting to, must be running an FTP server, in order for FTP to be usable.